# (R3 Corda 4.8) Selected output constraint: net.corda.core.contracts.WhitelistedByZoneAttachmentConstraint@1f102389 not satisfying

Tags: corda

I had cloned the [cordapp-kotlin-template](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin) . I've defined a state called LoadState which looks like this:

```
@BelongsToContract(LoadContract::class)
data class LoadState(
    val loadId: String,
    val transporterName: String? = null,
    val vehicleModel: String? = null,
    val regLicenseNo: String? = null,
    val totalWeight: Int? = null,
    val notes: String? = null,
    val suppliers: MutableList<SupplierDetailsModel> = mutableListOf(),
    val recycler: Party,
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(recycler)
) : QueryableState {
    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
        if (schema is LoadSchemaV1) {
            return PersistentLoadState(this.loadId)
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Schema.")
        }
    }

    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> {
        return listOf(LoadSchemaV1())
    }
}
```

When I use the application for the first time and issue a LoadState say **LO123** it works fine. The state is issued and recorded in the vault as well.
This is how my the LoadState issue flow looks like:

```
@Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNotary(CordaX500Name.parse("O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"))
        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_COMPONENTS

        val recyclerName = CordaX500Name(
            organisation = "MyRecycler",
            locality = "Mumbai",
            country = "IN"
        )

        val recycler = serviceHub.identityService.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(recyclerName)
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not find party Recycler.")

        val outputState = LoadState(
            loadId = req.loadId,
            loadDate = req.loadDate,
            transporterName = req.transporterName,
            vehicleModel = req.vehicleModel,
            regLicenseNo = req.regLicenseNo,
            totalWeight = req.totalWeight,
            assets = req.assets,
            suppliers = req.suppliers,
            recycler = recycler,
            notes = req.notes
        )

        val command = Command(LoadContract.Commands.Create(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_BUILDING

        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
            .addOutputState(outputState, LoadContract.ID)
            .addCommand(command)

        // signing the transaction
        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_SIGNING
        val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        // verifying the transaction
        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_VERIFICATION
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        // We finalise the transaction and then send it to the counterparty.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALIZATION

        val recyclerSession = initiateFlow(recycler)

        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx, listOf()))
    }
```

Now there's a requirement to add a new field to our LoadState:

> val myNewField: String? = null

After adding this new field to the LoadState I'm running the deployNodes command. Once the build folders are generated I'm copying the contents of the Node/cordapps folder to my old build Node/cordapps folder.

Now, while starting the nodes I'm running the migration commands (core schemas and app schemas). Once the migration process is complete and the nodes are up, I'm calling an api endpoint which invokes a flow which takes **L0123** as input, copies it, and modifies some params and create a new output state of type LoadState. The error is thrown at:
`txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)` in my UpdateLoadFlow. This is how my update flow looks like:

```
@Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNotary(CordaX500Name.parse("O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"))

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_COMPONENTS

        val recyclerName = CordaX500Name(
            organisation = "MyRecycler",
            locality = "Mumbai",
            country = "IN"
        )

        val recycler = serviceHub.identityService.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(recyclerName)
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not find party Recycler.")

        val inputState = QueryVault().queryLoadById(req.loadId, Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED, serviceHub.vaultService)
            ?: throw Exception("Load ${req.loadId} not found.")

        val vaultData = inputState.state.data
        var outputState = vaultData.copy(myNewField = "some new value");
        
        val command = Command(LoadContract.Commands.Update(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_BUILDING

        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
            .addInputState(inputState)
            .addOutputState(outputState, LoadContract.ID)
            .addCommand(command)

        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
        // signing the transaction
        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_SIGNING
        val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
        // verifying the transaction
        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_VERIFICATION

        // We finalise the transaction and then send it to the counterparty.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALIZATION
        val recyclerSession = initiateFlow(recycler)
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx, listOf()))
    }
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: What is the Corda version you are using? @Salman R

Comment: @SnehaDamle I tried using open source 4.8 and 4.8.5

Comment: After Corda4, by default states use SignatureConstraints. Your exception suggests that some states use WhiteListZoneConstraint. Firstly check how states are being issued using Whitelistzoneconstraint. The next step will be to upgrade to Signature Constraint from WhitelistZoneConstraint. For that, you will have to follow the constraint migration process as described here-https://medium.com/corda/unconstraint-signature-constraint-migration-e95a66789eab.

Comment: We can discuss more once you confirm the constraints associated with your states.

Comment: thanks @SnehaDamle for the response. To the best of my knowledge, I've not defined any constraints explicitly. So it must be using the default SignatureConstraint as you said. I've edited my question to include the LoadState issue, and modify flow. Please note: the error is not thrown at the time of issuing, it comes when I try to use this issued state as input and modify few params and create a new state.

Comment: Hi, Can you please paste the error? Also, can you do a fire this command at the terminal once you issue your state and confirm if it's SignatureConstraint or not.    run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.example.state.LoadState.

Comment: I ran that vaultQuery and IDK how but the constraint shows : 
constraint: !<net.corda.core.contracts.WhitelistedByZoneAttachmentConstraint> {}

This is the error: 
Selected output constraint: net.corda.core.contracts.WhitelistedByZoneAttachmentConstraint@42452bb not satisfying 356706D6C41CFF1AF56F43CA38D85F64AB62C4F8B873AA30E3190F6A9643A73A"

You can see in my flows that in transactionBuilder I'm not specifying any constraint (while issuing/updating).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our discussion in the above comments section, it appears that your states have been issued using Whitelist zone constraint.

Also looking at the code it is clear that you have not explicitly added Whitelist Zone constraints for your states.
Then there remain two more possibilities by which states are issued using Whitelist Zone constraint.

One is you are using some Corda version before 4 or you have included the necessary configs to include white list zone constraints in network bootstrapper as specified [here](https://cncorda.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/network-bootstrapper.html#whitelisting-contracts).
You have two options - either start from scratch and make sure you use Corda 4.

If you cannot start from scratch follow this path to first migrate the whitelist zone constraints to signature constraints, before running your UpdateLoadFlow. You can refer to [this](https://www.corda.net/blog/unconstraint-signature-constraint-migration/) blog which talks about constraint migration.